# how to check/know whether multiple countries/states are showing in current viewport in google map api

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have used `map.getBounds().contains(point)` and `containsLocation()` method. It tells us whether point exist in the viewport or not, but I'm not able to figure out how to find out that there are multiple countries/states in the viewport, and `.contains(point)` or `containsLocation()` checks for one point. So am I going to check hundreds or thousands of points? No. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: we can take few(say 5-10) latlng from the borders of countries and then we can check in viewport. but this is not a good solution. is it?

Comment: Where have you stored the borders of the countries/states?

Comment: i have created a dict containing all the latlng of countries (or states) in following format: x = {"IN": [lat, lng], "US": [lat, lng]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to collect these data on serverside, on clientside you would need to load all the boundaries for the desired regions(millions of points) , iterating over them would take too long with a scripting language.

What you need: a DataBase which supports spatial queries(e.g. Postgres with PostGIS, MySQL V5.6+, Google FusionTables).

These databases support the function `ST_INTERSECTS` which checks if a given column intersects a geometry(e.g. a RECTANGLE...in this case the viewport of the map).

A sample-implementation using FusionTables/jQuery may look like this:

```
    var map             = /*google maps instance*/,
        //ID of the FusionTable(table must be downloadable)
        tableId         = '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
        //your API-key(FusionTablesAPI must be enabled for the project)
        apiKey          = 'yourApiKey',
        //name of the column where the boundaries are stored
        locationColumn  = 'geometry',
        //names of the columns you like to receive
        columns         = ['Name'];

    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle',function(){
      var bounds  = map.getBounds().toUrlValue(),
          rect    = 'RECTANGLE(LATLNG('+map.getBounds()
                                        .getSouthWest().toUrlValue()+'),'+
                              'LATLNG('+map.getBounds()
                                        .getNorthEast().toUrlValue()+'))',
          query   = 'SELECT '+((columns.length)?"'"+columns.join("','")+"' ":' * ')+
                    ' FROM ' + tableId + 
                    ' WHERE ST_INTERSECTS('+locationColumn+','+rect+')';

      $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql='+
             encodeURIComponent(query)+'&key='+apiKey,function(data){
             if(bounds===map.getBounds().toUrlValue() && data.rows){
               console.log(data.rows.length + ' countries in viewport')
               if(data.rows.length){
                 var countries=[];
                 $.each(data.rows,function(i,o){
                   countries.push(o[0]);
                 });
                 console.log(countries.join(', '));
               }
             }
      },'jsonp');
    });
```

Fiddle:(printing a list with the names of the countries in viewport)

[**https://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/cgprmnk6/**](https://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/cgprmnk6/)